# how many channels in a CNN for sound classification?

Tags: tensorflow, classification, mfcc

I am a beginner with Tensorflow and machine learning in general.For my project I have to classify urban sound data.

I have extracted mfccs of my sample data and now I want to classify them by using a CNN in Tensorflow. I don't know how many channels I should use and why. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on a similar project and I found this paper useful with this.

http://karol.piczak.com/papers/Piczak2015-ESC-ConvNet.pdf